# Wordpress Issue after Moving Servers

Tags: php, jquery, css, wordpress

We are in the process of moving our Wordpress site to an AWS server. We think almost everything is functional, save for a few pages. For example, this page on the old server looks correct: http://52.41.5.94/free-business-marketing-resources/direct-mail-mapping-tool/
However, on the new server, the main content of the page overflows and goes over the footer. 
http://52.41.5.94/free-business-marketing-resources/direct-mail-mapping-tool/
The same issue is the case on several other pages.
I'm thinking maybe it's a footer error? Any insight or ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you seeing the javascript errors `Error: SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<' Url: http://52.41.5.94/wp-content/themes/movingtargets2015/js/  Line Number: 1` Or are you ignoring them?

Comment: Oh and both those links go to the same site, the new one I assume

Comment: Yes, I do see that pop-up error. I apologize, here is the link for the old site: http://movingtargets.com/free-business-marketing-resources/direct-mail-mapping-tool/

Comment: So as the LIVE site does not throw that error, maybe if you fix that error it will work properly on the new site. **Just a thought**

Comment: Thanks, I will work on fixing that error. however, other pages that are having the same problem do no throw that error, such as this one: http://52.41.5.94/free-business-marketing-resources/customer-tools/add-email-addresses/